# How do I use assemblies with PowerShell JEA?

Tags: powershell, assemblies, jea

I need to use an assembly in a start script in JEA (Just Enough Administration) but I get an error message when trying to use it.

The capabilities files contains

```
AssembliesToLoad = 'Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer'
```

But when I try to use it in a script

```
$parser = New-Object Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
```

I get the error

```
Enter-PsSession : Could not load file or assembly
'Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer' or one
of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Comment: Please share the script.

Comment: I did, it fails on the first line... So no use to provide the rest of it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least for Windows PowerShell 5.1, the [`JavaScriptSerializer` Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer?view=netframework-4.8.1) is part of `System.Web.Extensions.dll`, there is no such `Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer` assembly, in fact:

```bash
Add-Type -AssemblyName Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer
```

Will throw an error, however:

```bash
PS ..\pwsh> Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Web.Extensions
PS ..\pwsh> [System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer]

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     False    JavaScriptSerializer                     System.Object
```

So fixing your issue might be as simple as:

```
AssembliesToLoad = 'System.Web.Extensions'
```

Comment: I was so close, I tried adding `System.Web.Extensions` before as well, but apparently missed the last `s` in the name :/

Comment: I now noticed that `[Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer].Assembly.FullName` will provide me with the actual assembly of the class.

Comment: @Dennis right but you would need to load the assembly before knowing the assembly ;) its a chicken and egg game. The best recommendation I can give you is to search for the .NET doc for the class you want and then check the `Assembly:` section

Comment: Yes, but in this instance, I didn't have to load it before using the class in a normal session. I just need to know what assembly to be pre-approved for usage in my JEA session.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, dependencies wasn't an issue.

But to find dependencies using PowerShell for the class `[Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer]` you seem to be able to do

```
C:\> [Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer].Assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies()

Version        Name
-------        ----
4.0.0.0        mscorlib
4.0.0.0        System.Web
4.0.0.0        System.Drawing
4.0.0.0        System
4.0.0.0        System.Web.Services
4.0.0.0        System.Data.Services.Design
4.0.0.0        System.Configuration
4.0.0.0        System.ServiceModel
4.0.0.0        System.Xml
4.0.0.0        System.Core
4.0.0.0        System.Runtime.Serialization
4.0.0.0        System.Design
4.0.0.0        System.Data.Linq
4.0.0.0        System.Web.ApplicationServices
4.0.0.0        System.Data
4.0.0.0        System.ServiceModel.Activation
4.0.0.0        System.Data.Services.Client
4.0.0.0        System.Data.Entity
4.0.0.0        System.Windows.Forms
```